# Shared env vars between profiles when using yogthos/config in clojure?

Tags: clojure, environment-variables, config, profile

The https://github.com/yogthos/config approach let's you lay out per-profile env variables in separate files, like the below , in a `project.clj` .

Per the below, one can use `lein with-profile prod uberjar` or `lein with-profile dev repl` and the like.

But my issue is I have been unable to figure out how to place some common values into a `shared` area, accessible by `dev, stage, prod` profiles.

***Basic example***

```
(defproject edn-config-test "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
...
:profiles {:shared  {:resource-paths ["config/shared"]}
           :dev  {:resource-paths ["config/dev"]}
           :stage {:resource-paths ["config/stage"]} 
           :prod {:resource-paths ["config/prod"]}}
...
```

(with files)

```
config/shared/config.edn
config/dev/config.edn
config/stage/config.edn
config/prod/config.edn
```

**I tried this without luck**

`lein with-profile shared,prod lein`  , borrowing from  the composite approach in 
https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/stable/doc/PROFILES.md#composite-profiles

When I do that, I only get variables in `prod` profile, for example.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a limitation of `config`. I tried this (more explicit):

```
:profiles {:dev    {:resource-paths ["config/shared" "config/dev"]}
           :prod   {:resource-paths [ "config/prod"  "config/shared"]}}
```

However, the last file wins and the first is ignored.  So for `:dev` the shared stuff is ignored, and for `:prod` the prod stuff is ignored (like it doesn't exist):

```
config/dev/config.edn             => {:special-val :dev-val}
config/prod/config.edn            => {:special-val :prod-val}
cat config/shared/config.edn      => {:shared-val 42}
```

and results:

```
> lein with-profile prod  run
(:shared-val env)  => 42
(:special-val env) => nil

> lein with-profile dev   run
(:shared-val env)  => nil
(:special-val env) => :dev-val
```

Perhaps you'd like to submit an enhancement PR to the project?

---

Here is the problem.  It uses `io/resource` to read `config.edn`, which implicitly expects there to be **only one** file `config.edn` *anywhere on the classpath*:

```
(defn- read-config-file [f]
  (try
    (when-let [url (io/resource f)]
      (with-open [r (-> url io/reader PushbackReader.)]
        (edn/read r))) ...

(read-config-file "config.edn")
```

So you'd have to get away from the hard-coded filename `config.edn`, and make something like `config-dev.edn`, `config-prod.edn`, and `config-shared.edn`. At least then they could all live in a single `./resources` dir.